# jQuery get updated position of an element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to track the position of an animated element, there are two buttons; one to move the element up, the other to move down, and each should print the new position after moving..here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
          position:absolute;
          background-color:#abc;
          left:50px;
          top :50px;
          width:90px;
          height:90px;
          margin:5px;
        }
    </style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#up").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"top": "-=50px"}, "slow");
  top  = $(".block").position().top;
left = $(".block").position().left; 
  $("#position").html("X: "+left+" , Y:"+top) ;
});

$("#down").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"top": "+=50px"}, "slow");
  top  = $(".block").position().top;
  left = $(".block").position().left; 
  $("#position").html("X: "+left+" , Y:"+top) ;
});
});

</script>

</head>
    <body>
        <button id="down">v</button> <button id="up">^</button>
        <div class="block"></div><br/>
        <p id="position"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

it doesn't work as I want, I get the same result for each move: `X: 50 , Y:[object Window]`
How to fix that? is the functions I used `position().left` and `position().top` right to get the X, and Y of the element ?

Comment: Try [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) instead of position, and switch over your `click()` calls to `on()` since `click()` (which really is a call to `bind()`) [is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: on() instead of click doesn't work "no move upon click", and offset() gives the same result except the left value changes: `X: 55 , Y:[object Window]`

Comment: I suspect you're using the format `$('#down').on('click` try using `$(document).on('click', '#down` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a jsfiddle to show the working result:
http://jsfiddle.net/6JZCW/2/

Two things I noticed: 1, you were calling

> position()

instead of

> offset()

the difference being, position() is relative to the parent element, where offset is relative to the document.

2, you were having some variable name issues where top and left are already defined (i think part of jquery, but I'm not certain). So, renaming the top and left to 'y' and 'x' respectively, it works as I believe you intended.

**Here's another update with left and right included:**
http://jsfiddle.net/6JZCW/3/

Comment: and these values are they the actual element's coordinates? or another representation?

Comment: they are the actual elements coordinates relative to the document--that is, the upper left corner of the element

Comment: updated--added left and right functionality to test the x-axis

Comment: it update the position after .animate() finish, what if I want it to update the position during animating? I mean per frame rate or something?